# round() function in python 2 and python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, rounding

I'm solving some coding challenges on CoderByte and unfortunately they provide Python2. One thing I noticed is that the round() function is giving different outputs on python3 and python2. When i write this on python 2:

```
print int(round(100/60))
```

I get output of 1 (please explain why)

But on python 3 the same command gives 2 which is correct.

Comment: I posted a new question because I didn't know the problem. Now that I know the problem, I know that this has already been answered. Some other person might have the same problem and search for this. He can find the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the rounding, but the interpretation of `/`.

In python 2 if dividing 2 integers with `/` you get an integer not a float.

In python 3 you get a float if you use `/` - the "pure" integer division is done by using `//`.

Python 2:

```
print(100/60) # ==> 1
print(100/60.0) # ==> 1.6666666666...
```

Python 3:

```
print (100/60) # ==> 1.6666
print (100//60) # ==> 1
```

They both get rounded accordingly, but if you input a 1 into round, it will result in 1.

You can read more about the reason for the changed behaviour here: [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

> The current division (`/`) operator has an ambiguous meaning for numerical arguments: it returns the floor of the mathematical result of division if the arguments are ints or longs, but it returns a reasonable approximation of the division result if the arguments are floats or complex. This makes expressions expecting float or complex results error-prone when integers are not expected but possible as inputs.
>
> We propose to fix this by introducing different operators for different operations: `x/y` to return a reasonable approximation of the mathematical result of the division ("true division"), `x//y` to return the floor ("floor division"). We call the current, mixed meaning of `x/y` "classic division".

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

In python 2 the divide operator on integers returns integer, so `100/60==1`. This unintuitive C-like behaviour was changed in python 3.

To make this code work properly in python 2 you should convert one of the integers to float: `print int(round(100/60.))`, that `.` means `60.0`.